# Pronunciation of "our": One or two syllables?

Tags: pronunciation

It seems to me that certain words can be pronounced with either one, or two, syllables:

- "our"
- "fire"
- "dire"

Specifically for "our", I hear it said as "Au-er", with two syllables, and as "aur", with one syllable.
Probably there can be variations when speaking formally, properly, slowly, clearly, and without slang, and without quick, slurred speech.

How can one know whether one pronunciation is incorrect, or whether both are equally acceptable?

Comment: Both are fine. The slower you speak, the more this dipthong tends to sound like two syllables.

Comment: For the closers, the question is about which one to use and under what circumstances (maybe dialect? register?) Dictionaries don't explain that.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the dictionary for this too.

A full stop (or a hyphen) indicates the syllable division in the IPA pronunciation.

For "our", [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/our) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/our) agree that in American English both are acceptable, whereas British English is listed with only the single syllable. For words in "-ire", Cambridge doesn't list an American pronunciation sounding like two syllables... but I must admit that to my ear, the sound files they provide sound like that.

Comment: That's not what *Cambridge* says — for British English, it says /aʊə(r/) or /ɑː(r)/, which, except for dropping final /r/s in British English, is exactly the same as what Webster gives (although using different phonetic notation).

Comment: @PeterShor For Cambridge, That's what I wrote, isn't it ? and Webster has ˈau̇(-ə)r  with a hyphen in the bracketed version.It

Comment: There's no full stop mark in the IPA, /aʊər/ /ɑːr/, whereas when there are 2 syllables such as for glower, there is : /ˈɡlaʊ.ər/